# PHP Regex Pattern To Match And Strip Out Embedded Images in Text Email

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I strip out embedded images in text based emails with the following pattern?

[cid:B54FD59F-8DE7-4ED1-A0C7-19E52F83A8D7]

Comment: what you want to extract from this ?

Comment: I have a large body of text with these guys sprinkled throughout.  I'd like to remove them altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are guids, this regex will provide a clean match and replace with empty string

```
$pattern = '/\[cid\:[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{12}\]/i';
$formattedString = preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex to extract `[cid:B54FD59F-8DE7-4ED1-A0C7-19E52F83A8D7]` like patterns from your text body,

```
\[cid:.*\]
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nZ3tL9/1)

Comment: Might want to make that non greedy in case there is a `]` later in the email body.

Answer (score 0):

```
\[cid:[^\]]*\]
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/34

```
$re = ""\\[cid:[^\\]]*\\]"";#regex101 bug
$re = "/\\[cid:[^\\]]*\\]/"; 
$str = "askdaskjd\nsad\nas\nd\n[cid:B54FD59F-8DE7-4ED1-A0C7-19E52F83A8D7]\na\nds\nad\nsa\nd\n[cid:B54FD59F-8DE7-4ED1-A0C7-19E52F83A8D7]\n\nasdasd";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: What's the deal with the double quotes? Is that a regex101.com bug...? weird.

Comment: How in the world did you make it do that?! :D

Comment: @l'L'l dont have github account.Please post a bug if you have one. :)

Comment: @l'L'l i got it.I selected python.The delimiter is `"` there.Then i got code for `PHP` from code generator and that generater that error.You can post steps to reproduce as well :)

Comment: I can inject code there. Not good... I switched the link back to your original one. Actually, I'm going to delete it altogether :)

Comment: @l'L'l aah!!!!!got it!!!!!!! now you can hack into regex101 and do some nasty stuff? :P

Comment: The site is too useful, so definitely no nastiness :) ... They've taken pretty good precautions against obvious injections it looks like too.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a pattern such as:

```
(\[cid:(?:[0-9A-Z-]{7,8}){5}\])
```

If you wanted to include lowercase characters use `i` (ignore case) after the `/`.

```
$reg = "/(\[cid:(?:[0-9A-Z-]{7,8}){5}\])/";
$sub = "";

$result = preg_replace($reg, $sub, $str);
```

Example:

https://regex101.com/r/vK8eX1/1